# In MongoDB, how to fetch items where child array matches with condition and in result any child items that matched with condition be filtered

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, projection

I have this document:

[image]

**JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "website": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "website-1"
    },
    "_id": "64510561da44c5dc5b0e8935",
    "items": [
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "x"
        },
        "price": 53410,
        "_id": "64510561da44c5dc5b0e8936"
      },
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "y"
        },
        "price": 2000,
        "_id": "64510561da44c5dc5b0e8937"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "website": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "website-2"
    },
    "_id": "645105ff86b991ba179b32f7",
    "items": [
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "x"
        },
        "price": 7250,
        "_id": "645105ff86b991ba179b32f8"
      },
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "z"
        },
        "price": 888,
        "_id": "645105ff86b991ba179b32f9"
      },
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 4,
          "title": "w"
        },
        "price": 444,
        "_id": "645105ff86b991ba179b32fa"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "website": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "website-3"
    },
    "_id": "245105ff86b991ba179b32f7",
    "items": [
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 4,
          "title": "w"
        },
        "price": 333,
        "_id": "845105ff86b991ba179b32fa"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**What I want:**

- Find by `websiteId`
- Find by `coinId`
- Filter returned `items` in result: In each record of result if we check the `items`, every items be included that `coin.id` is in `coinIds` array

**What I expect as JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "website": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "website-1"
    },
    "_id": "64510561da44c5dc5b0e8935",
    "items": [
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "x"
        },
        "price": 53410,
        "_id": "64510561da44c5dc5b0e8936"
      },
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "y"
        },
        "price": 2000,
        "_id": "64510561da44c5dc5b0e8937"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "website": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "website-2"
    },
    "_id": "645105ff86b991ba179b32f7",
    "items": [
      {
        "coin": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "x"
        },
        "price": 7250,
        "_id": "645105ff86b991ba179b32f8"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
```

**My current code:**

```
const websiteIds = [1,2];
const coinIds = [1,2];

const result = await MyModel.find(
    {
      'website.id': { $in: websiteIds },
      'items.coin.id': { $in: coinIds },
    }
  );
```

It return correct filtered records by `websiteIds` but in each record all items of `items` field be returned if `coin.id` of one of items be matched with `coinIds`. I want `Items` in returned JSON be filtered by `coinIds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to be able to project more than one item, a simple `find` with projection will not do the job. One option is to use a pipeline with `$filter`:

```
const result = await MyModel.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      "website.id": {$in: websiteIds},
      "items.coin.id": {$in: coinIds}
  }},
  {$set: {
      items: {$filter: {
          input: "$items",
          cond: {$in: ["$$this.coin.id", coinIds]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TIa3aa4Ri7M)